# After Finishing C# Program In Release Mode, How Do I Put App on CD to Put on Someone Elses Computer?

Tags: c#, .net, exe

I just wrote a Windows Form C# program for my mom for Mother's Day.  It has been build in Release mode.  How do I put the program on cd so she can run it on her computer?

Comment: Are you having trouble locating the `exe` file or are you worried about the .NET dependencies?

Comment: Similar, but not dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584967/burn-setup-project-to-cd

Comment: Just the Copy the Release Folder into CD, Make SUre The Other machine Should have .NET Framework Version same the .Net Version of the APP.

Comment: I'm worried about the .Net dependencies.  But was also curious of exactly what files I put on the cd.  Do I just put the .exe file or other files from the project folder.  Furthermore, do I just copy the folder on to the cd or do I have to burn it?  Also, what if she doesn't have .Net on her machine?  Is there away around executing the program?

Comment: Unless you've explicitly referenced other assemblies, then only the `exe` will be required for a simple WinForms application. There is no way to run it without the .NET Framework installed, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This is the first program I wrote without any direction :)  I've never had to put on cd before.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the .exe file present in the Release Folder of your project and make sure .Net is installed on target machine.

Comment: .Net2 will almost surely be installed. Does [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756885.aspx) check and install all later .Nets on demand?